# How to take the derivative of a function $F(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

The function $F(x)=\int_{-1}^{x}\sqrt{1-t^2}dt$.

I believe this to be the representation of the area under the curve between $-1$ and $x$, where $\int_{-1}^{x}\sqrt{1-t^2}dt$ is a function of $x$: $F(x)$.

The area of integration changes with respect to $x$.

$F(x)$ where $x = 1$ evaluates to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

My question is: How do I determine $F'(x)$?

Comment: [Fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $F'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{-1}^x\sqrt{1-t^2}dt$, Let $G(t)$ be the antiderivative of $\sqrt{1-t^2}$, i.e.

$G'(t)=\sqrt{1-t^2},\,\forall t\in [-1,x]$

Then $F'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{-1}^x\sqrt{1-t^2}dt=\frac{d}{dx}(G(x)-G(-1))=G'(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Comment: Is $-\sqrt{1+x^2}==\sqrt{1-x^2}$?

Comment: @alx, not necessarily $-\sqrt{1+1^2}=-\sqrt{2}$, but $\sqrt{1-1^2}=\sqrt{0}=0$, why?

Comment: The answer to this is $\sqrt{1+x^2}$, not $\sqrt{1-x^2}$.